# Confused about definitions in formula complexity ($\Sigma_1$, $\Delta_0$, $\Delta^1_0$, etc)

Tags: logic, set-theory, definition, first-order-logic

There are so many definitions of formula complexity around and in so many contexts that I'm seriously confused. Say we're working in the language of set theory.

I understand that $\Delta_0$ formula is one whose quantifiers are all bounded (or is quantifier free). These are absolute (for transitive models) regardless of theory. $\Sigma_1$ are $\Delta_0$ with a leading unbounded existential quantifier, and so on. $\Delta_1$ is something that is both $\Sigma_1$ and $\Pi_1$. Given a theory $T$, a $\Delta^T_0$ formula is one that is provably equivalent to a $\Delta_0$ formula and so is absolute for transitive models of $T$.

We say $\Delta_1$ formulas are recursive correct? Or is this only if the $\Delta_1$ formulas have quantifiers which range over $\omega$ (or something else countable), i.e, do we actually mean $\Delta^0_1$? But then that formula explicitly has bounded quantifiers and thus should be considered $\Delta_0$, no? Similarly, $\Sigma^1_1$, $\Pi^1_1$ and $\Delta^1_1$ formulas are those that quantify over the reals (something like Baire space for instance). Again these are explicitly bounded (by reals in this case) and thus $\Delta_0$ aren't they?

Is it about context?

In the context of absoluteness, $\Sigma^1_n$ and $\Pi^1_n$ are bounded and thus $\Delta_0$ and thus absolute no matter how high the $n$? And in the context of recursion, do we mean $\Delta_1$ to mean $\Delta^0_1$ (and similarly $\Sigma^0_1$ for computably enumerable) for something bounded by naturals, and $\Delta^1_1$ for something that quantifiers over reals? So is a set computed by a turing machine with an oracle ($\Delta^1_1$ I think) absolute for all transitive models? That doesn't sound right.

Can someone please lay out the scenarios and contexts that all of these are used in, and how they relate to one another? How does $\Sigma_1$ relate to $\Sigma_1^0$?

A big problem for me is that $\Delta_0$ sets included anything with bounded quantification but it seems to me like you could still have a *huge* amount of quantification and complexity behind bounded quantifiers.

Another thing is: what does it mean to be recursive in terms of quantifier complexity: I think it means $\Delta^0_1$ (so quantifying over naturals or something similar). Is that correct?